# How can I calculate the working days starting from the hours in the "Work" field in Microsoft Project?

Tags: ms-project

probably a trivial question about Microsoft Project.

I have a task like this one:

[image]

As you ca see there is the **Work** field that contains the worked hours. There is a way to set it in days instead hours?
I also tried to manually set **10 days** instead **80 hors** but Project automatically convert it in **80 hrs** value.

There is a way to set it directly in days? Or could be interesting set it in hours (as it is now) but add something like a custom field (something like "days of work") that simply execute this simple calculation: **work field value / 8**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In Project go to, File > Options > Schedule group. Set the "scheduling options for this project", "work entered in", to days.

However, are you perhaps confusing duration and work? They are two different concepts in Project. Duration is the time span during which as task is performed. Work is the effort by one or more resources to perform the task. Duration is most often expressed in days whereas work is most often expressed in hours.